WPF DataGrid Format Exception on Numeric Cell Preventing IDataErrorInfo Validation
I'm working with a WPF DataGrid bound to an ObservableCollection where Product implements IDataErrorInfo for validation. I want to catch and display validation errors when a user enters an incorrect value, such as entering text instead of a number. I can catch the errors and display then on any Text cells, but not numeric, because I see that WPF is throwing a format exception before IDataErrorInfo validation is triggered, bypassing my custom error handling.
Example, I enter a text in a numeric cell, the cell border turns red, a format exception is thrown, but public string this[string propertyName] is never triggered.
How can I make wpf skip/ignore/handle the format exceptions so that IDataErrorInfo validation is triggered in numeric cell?

How would your viewmodel know that the value was invalid? If the value entered can't be parsed as the type of the bound property, then it can't be stored in the bound property. As far as the viewmodel knows, the user hasn't entered anything.

I wouldn't try to skip format exceptions, it's good to have and it's harmless, ensuring your IDataErrorInfo validation need not to parse anything. If you insist, then using string as data types everywhere and parsing it yourself is an option. Or just use custom validation rule (example).
